# is there a ubuntu appium inspector for android

Tags: ubuntu, appium

does appium have inspector for android that runs on ubuntu? If so, how to install it.
I have did enough searching. I'm pointed to MAC version of appium inspector, but not able to find if for Ubuntu. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

basically we need inspector for viewing name, id and other property of element in the android app, which I can use for test automation with appium.

We can use "Ui Automator Viewer"  which we can find in android sdk folder "sdk/tools/uiautomatorviewer".

Comment: I can't find "Ui Automator Viewer" there.

Comment: In Windows it's `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin`. There you can find  `uiautomatorviewer.bat` file.

Comment: Check this path: ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin

Answer (score 2):

If you have already installed android sdk and configured path skip step 1 and go to step 2 directly.

Step1:
Download SDK for linux. Extract to home folder in linux

Then configure your sdk path in .bashrc file

To configure Type 
       gedit .bashrc at terminal

Opens an text editor, type the folowing and save

```
  export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/adt/sdk"

  export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"

  export PATH=${PATH}:~/adt/sdk/tools

  export PATH=${PATH}:~/adt/sdk/platform-tools
```

Step2: 
Then type uiautomatorviewer at your terminal to start uiautomatorviewer and get details of elements you want to inspect.

Answer (score 1):

You will find UI Automator Viewer in your SDK folder under >tools>bin>uiautomatorviewer. Launch it using terminal. In terminal, cd to the path and lauch uiautomatorviewer by entering ./uiautomatorviewer